# SwiftUI offset items in ScrollView under another view

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I have a `VStack` with some content at the top of my app, then a `ScrollView` on the bottom, with these views being seperated with a `Divider`. Is there any way to offset the scrollView such that it starts slightly tucked under the `Divider` and the top view?

Here is an example image of what I want:

[image]

The numbers are in a `ScrollView` and the top content is simply `Color.white` in this example.

If I apply a simply y `offset`, though, I get this:

[image]

The number is vertically shifted up, but not "tucked" under.

Is there an easy way to get the "tucked" result? I'm sure I could use a ZStack or something, but that seems like a lot of work, especially because I don't know how large the top content will be.

Example Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Color.white.frame(height: 100)
        
            Divider()
        
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(0..<20) { number in
                    Text("\(number)")
                }
            }
            .offset(y: -8)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try a negative padding and .clipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you just need padding for scroll view, like

[image]

```
ScrollView {
    ForEach(0..<20) { number in
        Text("\(number)")
    }
}
.padding(.top, -8)   // << here !!
.clipped()
```